# How does one manually throw a "overflow exception" in C++?

Tags: c++, exception

I am rather new to exceptions. In a part of my program if a specific variable goes beyond a certain value I want to manually throw an exception which will say that the variable has gone outside of accepted range. The variable being 16 bits can still hold the "invalid" values but under normal program operation it will only hold a subset of the possible values it can hold.

How do I generate this specific type of exception?

Comment: Please ask your question your rubber duck and delete it (not the duck)

Comment: C++ does not have the concept of an "overflow exception".  Instead, overflowing integers will silently trigger undefined behavior and/or wrapping. If you want a specific type of exception, you will need to create your own.

Comment: Reopened because OP is not trying to detect an actual overflow, but trying to detect some kind of "logical out-of-range" instead.

Comment: well, if I have to "create my own exception" then I shall just look into it then

Comment: What is wrong here: I have not  "marked [this question] as duplicate" !!!

Comment: Dupe candidate would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148511/limiting-range-of-value-types-in-c for example.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Oki.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agghhh!! Stop it!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

```
throw std::out_of_range("Your value doesn't belong to a valid range");
```

The class `std::out_of_range` is defined in

```
#include <stdexcept>
```

Documentation: [std::out_of_range - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range)