# Trapping a Variable in a Range

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I want to keep a variable in the range of [min, max]. For this purpose, I wrote this function:

```
void trapVar(int& var, int& min, int& max) {
   if(var < min) var = min;
   else if(var > max) var = max;
}
```

Is there any efficient or better (or any other implementation) way to realize this function? Maybe this implementation is the simplest one? You can comment on the coding style also.

Comment: The standard library provides: `std::clamp`

Comment: Like Mansoor said. Here is the link to cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp

Comment: There is no point in passing `min` and `max` as references. You also probably want to verify that `min <= max`.

Comment: Only problem with `std::clamp()` is it's C++17 and the question is tagged C++11.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Limiting range of value types in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148511/580083).

Comment: You can use implementation of the `std::clamp()` from cppreference to your code :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments. As you all suggested, I will look at the implementation of std::clamp().

Comment: And I guess `to clamp` is the right vocabulary instead of `to trap` :)

Comment: good practice is to have ```const``` references for your read only ```min``` and ```max```