# Limiting range of value type in modern C++

Tags: c++, c++17

We have to restrict the range of order of a polynomial from 1 to 51. I can see the following  post on the same.

[Limiting range of value types in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148511/limiting-range-of-value-types-in-c)

Does C++ 17 support a better and direct feature for this?

Comment: As in a `std` library construct that does min and max values via template? No, I don't think so.

Comment: what do you mean with "better" ? As it stands this question seems to be a duplicate of the Q&A you link. Can you explain why the answer there does not answer your question?

Comment: Do you mean [`std::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp)?